# Why do lightdm and Xorg cause so much CPU load on my Xubuntu 20.04?

Tags: xorg, lightdm, cpu

What is it that loads the CPU so unreasonably? (Lenovo W530 with Xubuntu 20.04.4 LTS, currently using kernel 5.4.0-110-generic x86_64).

After an upgrade, the CPU on my Lenovo W530 laptop spins at an increased (but not yet maximum) speed. The load indicator shows 267 processes, the quad-core CPU is over 27% utilized and 1.7 GiB of 6.7 GiB RAM (according to Taskmanager). All programs react quite delayed.

In the task manager I see that `/usr/sbin/lightdm` (with only little CPU load) calls `/usr/lib/xorg/Xorg -core :0 -seat seat0 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -nolisten tcp vt7 -novtswitch` and that causes 25% CPU load (i.e. one complete thread of my Intel i7-3520M CPU @ 2.90GHz CPU) and say 101.5 MiB RSS.

Meanwhile I have found out that the memory consumption sometimes continually accumulates. After quite some run time, even some swap space is used and even large amounts of memory stay in use, even after all application programs have been closed.

In order to find out what eats up all my memory I tried top with this command, which lets me direct its output to a file q:

`top -c -n 1 -d 1 -w 256 > q`

I have to set the width of the terminal wide enough to not truncate the command lines invoking the CPU stressing task, -w 512 seems to not work when the terminal width is small:

In a lucky situation when the whole computer does not acts sluggish and I get:

```
adalbert@W:~$ top -c -n 1 -d 1 -w 256 > q
adalbert@W:~$ cat q
top - 23:20:20 up  2:22,  1 user,  load average: 1,14, 1,24, 1,23
Tasks: 258 gesamt,   2 laufend, 256 schlafend,   0 gestoppt,   0 Zombie
%CPU(s): 26,9 be, 11,9 sy,  0,0 ni, 61,2 un,  0,0 wa,  0,0 hi,  0,0 si,  0,0 st
MiB Spch :   6656,3 gesamt,   2318,3 frei,   2264,9 belegt,   2073,0 Puff/Cache
MiB Swap:   2048,0 gesamt,   2048,0 frei,      0,0 belegt.   4072,7 verfü Spch 
PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     ZEIT+ BEFEHL
1215 root      20   0  506648 165776  73068 R 100,0   2,4 135:17.46 /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg -core :0 -+
2435 adalbert  20   0  422820  71496  39232 S  12,5   1,0   0:51.80 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/tou+
2003 adalbert  20   0  294092  87384  17492 S   6,2   1,3  11:48.71 xfsettingsd --display :0.0 --+
7727 adalbert  20   0  428024  77616  31952 S   6,2   1,1   0:31.07 /usr/bin/xfce4-terminal
34284 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   6,2   0,0   0:00.04 [kworker/3:1-events]
1 root      20   0  167876  11804   8388 S   0,0   0,2   0:01.28 /sbin/init splash
```

`lightdm` is the display manager. **Why does it call `Xorg -core …?` in this special way?**

**Why does it use that much CPU power?**

**How can I cope with this situation?**

Comment: Same (or very similar) problem here on a Lenovo T440p [Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4710MQ CPU @ 2.50GHz] with Xubuntu 20.04.4 ... I have no clue what causes this.

Comment: top output:     
    `PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND`                                                                                                                 
 `1200 root      20   0  419456 187800 133780 R 100,0   1,2  21:34.54 /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg -core :0 -seat seat0 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -nolisten tcp vt7 -novtswitch`